# How to get a word entered by the user to exit a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, exit, break

I am working on a program where the user is prompted to enter the names of Contestants participating in a competition and their scores from the judges. All of this is in a for-loop with a counter to keep track of the number of Contestants. Since the number of contestants is unknown the user is supposed to enter 'Done' to exit the loop.

All of the ways I have found to exit a loop is with a boolean which does not work with 'string' variables.
I was wondering if there was a way to exit the loop by inputting the word 'Done'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   //for name entry of contestants
#include <iomanip>  //rounding and point perceision
#include <fstream>  //write names and averages to a file for storage

using namespace std;

double calcAvgScore(int, int, int, int, int);   //calculates the average after the highest and lowest scores are found 
double findHighest(int, int, int, int, int);    //finds the highest of the 5 scores 
double findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);     //finds the lowest of the 5 scores

int main()
{
    string cName;   //name of the contestant
    int jScore1, jScore2, jScore3, jScore4, jScore5;    //scores of each judge
    double AvgScore;    //average of the scores
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("NamesAndAverage.txt");

    for (int count = 1;; count++)
    {
        if (count = 1)
            cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no Contestants enter ""Done""";
        else
            cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no more Contestants please enter ""Done""";
        cin >> cName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `break;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the condition directly to your loop,

```
for (int count = 1; cName != "Done"; count++)
```

or use `if` and `break` inside the loop.

```
if( cName == "Done" )
     break;
```

You can also use ternary in your loop contents:

```
cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no" << (count > 1) ? "more" : "" << "Contestants enter ""Done"";
cin >> cName;
```

Comment: *"can also simplify"* - yikes!  If any ternary-operator "simplification" were to be contemplated, it ought to remove all the redundancy: `std::cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no " << (count > 1 ? "more" : "") << "contestants enter \"Done\"";`.

Comment: Using the ternary operator like this is hardly simplification. Just use an `if`. The guideline is that the ternary operator should only be used if you use its result, rather than discard it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Never new that guideline before, thank you!

Comment: @TonyD Yes, yours was a better approach towards simplification.

Comment: @raymelfrancisco: You're welcome. As a matter of fact, TonyD's example is a good one, because it uses the result of the operator. That's just much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could `break` out of the loop:

```
for (int count = 1;; count++)
{
    // prompt for input, snipped
    cin >> cName;
    if (cName == "Done") 
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `break;`:

```
if (cName == "Done") {
    break;
}
```

Also, there is another typo in your program. With

```
if (count = 1)
```

you are actually resetting `count` to 1 every time. This should be:

```
if (count == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as handling `"Done"`, you should be checking your input and output operations for success, both can be done with `if`/`else` statements:

```
if (std::ofstream outFile("NamesAndAverage.txt"))
    for (int count = 1;; count++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << "."
                "If there are no ";
        if (count > 1) std::cout << "more ";
        std::cout << "contestants enter \"Done\"\n";
        if (cin >> cName && cName != "Done")
            // use cName...
        else
            break;
     }
else
     std::cerr << "unable to open output file\n";
```